# Remote Schedule Windows Update and Shutdown with Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-remoting

I am currently trying to create an automation script with [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).
The script I'm using is [Force Install Updates on Remote Computer](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Force-Install-Updates-on-ef821f9a) The script allows a remote computer to creates a scheduled task to perform a windows update on a host computer.

**Question**

How can I modify this script to shut down the remote computer after the scheduled task has updated the operating system?

Comment: Did you bother to read the Q&A section on the site that you linked to? That question is explicitly asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new action to the scheduled task.

```
Action:  Start a program
Program/script:  shutdown
Add arguments:  /p /f         (to switch off)
Add arguments:  /r /f /t 01   (to reboot)
Start in:   <leave it empty>
```

A remote solution would be to start "shutdown.exe" with Powershell

```
Start-Process "shutdown.exe" -ArgumentList (" /s /f /t 01 /m \\{0}" -f $RemoteComputer) -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Another one to use WMI, see [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa394058.aspx).

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $RemoteComputer -EnableAllPrivileges).Win32Shutdown(12)
```

Until Powershell 3 "Stop-Computer" is available, see [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849839.aspx).

```
Stop-Computer -ComputerName $RemoteComputer
```

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed response ; its really helpful.
What are the parameters (-NoNewWindow -Wait) at the end of the second code block?

    'A remote solution would be to start "shutdown.exe" with Powershell

Start-Process "shutdown.exe" -ArgumentList (" /s /f /t 01 /m \\{0}" -f $RemoteComputer) -NoNewWindow -Wait'

I have read the documentation on shutdown.exe but it doesn't have any information on these params.
[shutdown.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503.aspx)